# Starting x amount of threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to start additional threads.

```
Console.WriteLine("enter how many");
threadsToRun = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());     
        
for (int i = 0; i < threadsToRun; i++)
{
   Thread thread = new Thread(DoWork);
   thread.Name = $"threadname{i}";
   thread.Start();
}
```

My DoWork function, which is what the additional threads will run:

```
static void DoWork()
{
   string message = Console.ReadLine();
   while (true)
   {
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
      Console.WriteLine("Thread#{0} is now working!", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
      Console.WriteLine(message);
   }
}
```

When I run this code, it doesn't let me assign the message for thread[i], before it asks me to assign the message for thread[i++]. An example if I set threadsToRun = 5, I end up with the cmd prompting me for 5 ReadLines as once:

```
Enter message for threadname0:
Enter message for threadname1:
Enter message for threadname3:
Enter message for threadname2:
Enter message for threadname4:
```

Are there any way, so I can assign the message for each thread without showing all at once, then when I assign first thread, next thread prompts me to enter and so on..
I imagine something like this:

```
Enter message for threadname0:
Desired Message I Wanna Store Into the threadname0 string.

Enter message for threadname1
Desired Message I Wanna Store Into the threadname1 string.
```

Until all threads have been created with the strings I assigned to them.

Regards, hope it makes sense! :)

Comment: What is your actual goal? Creating threads just to take input does not make much sense, and there are better tools that raw threads to use.

Comment: my goal is to create multiple threads, to scrape multiple websites at once. would there be better methods to achieve this?

Comment: Multiple threads are 100% not necessary for scraping websites.

Comment: A parallel.Foreach would be neater, possibly in combination with a concurrentQueue wrapped in a blockingCollection.

Comment: Here is a great resource about multithreading, if you have time for reading: [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) by Joseph Albahari.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since you cannot type in all messages in parallel you would need to prepare them before starting the threads and pass the message into the method as parameter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < threadsToRun; i++)
{
    string message = Console.ReadLine();
    Thread thread = new Thread(()=> DoWork(message));
    thread.Name = $"threadname{i}";
    thread.Start();
}

static void DoWork(string message)
{
    while (true)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(2000);
       Console.WriteLine("Thread#{0} is now working!", Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
       Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

> Are there any way, I can wait to start all the threads created with the messages, until I have assigned each threads string message? Then when I choose to, do something like allThreads.start();

Yes you would need to collect all the threads first in a collection and then iterate later over it and start them:

```
List<Thread> allThreads = new List<Thread>();

for (int i = 0; i < threadsToRun; i++)
{
    string message = Console.ReadLine();
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => DoWork(message));
    thread.Name = $"threadname{i}";
    allThreads.Add(thread);
    
}

foreach (var thread in allThreads)
{
    thread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Are there any way, I can wait to start all the threads created with the messages, until I have assigned each threads string message?
Then when I choose to, do something like allThreads.start();

Comment: @Doctuh Yes, I made an edit and added such a solution to my answer